# How to locate a sub-direcotry?

Tags: command-line, directory

I want to locate a sub-directory `build/debug` within a folder

Are there any shell command that can do this?

Answer (score 6):

This should do it.

```
find . -type d -path '*/build/debug'
```

Test harness:

```
$ mkdir -p tester/{1..3}/build/debug
$ find tester -type d -path '*/build/debug'
tester/1/build/debug
tester/2/build/debug
tester/3/build/debug
```

Answer (score 3):

If you turn on globstar (with  `shopt -s globstar`), you can use double-asterisk for recursive wildcards in bash.

```
$ mkdir -p tester/{1..3}/build/debug
$ mkdir -p tester/anotherlevel/{1..3}/build/debug
$ mkdir -p tester/anotherlevel/yetanother/{1..3}/build/debug
$ shopt -s globstar
$ file tester/**/build/debug
tester/1/build/debug:                         directory
tester/2/build/debug:                         directory
tester/3/build/debug:                         directory
tester/anotherlevel/1/build/debug:            directory
tester/anotherlevel/2/build/debug:            directory
tester/anotherlevel/3/build/debug:            directory
tester/anotherlevel/yetanother/1/build/debug: directory
tester/anotherlevel/yetanother/2/build/debug: directory
tester/anotherlevel/yetanother/3/build/debug: directory
```

I'm using file here just to show what we're talking about but you can use this for all sorts of things.

Answer (score 1):

The grep way

```
find /your/sub/dir -type d -print0
```

prints all your files to the console. Now only output the ones you want to see by using grep

```
find /home/tim/Apps -type d -print0 | grep -FzZ "debug/build"
```

Answer (score -1):

Execute the command

```
find -name 'foldername'
```

This will find all folders (and files) of that name and show the path to it.
The search start from the current folder you are in downwards.
So if you have no idea where it is then `cd /` first so that you are in the root top folder. You might also want to add `sudo` in front of the command to make sure the search checks folder you do not have permissions too.

Comment: This won't do because build/debug is not a unix filename. This call will return a warning, because "build/debug" will always be false for this particular foldername. "Use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ "debug/build"' instead" the console says if this command is issued...